# Changing colour for text highlighting using ::selection jumbles up text

Tags: css, colors, selection, highlighting

I've been finding that text I highlight jumbles itself up in some of the sites I've built.

Here's an example - try highlighting the large heading on this page to see what I mean http://revelation.org.uk

I've narrowed it down to this code:

```
::-moz-selection    { background:#6c5ea6; color:#f7f7f7; text-shadow: none; }
::selection     { background:#6c5ea6; color:#f7f7f7; text-shadow: none; }
```

When I remove `color:#f7f7f7;` it fixes the problem, but I want to use this colour for highlighted text if I can.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser are you experiencing this in?

Comment: Chrome does act strange indeed. Seems like a bug to me. Or perhaps you can only sit color in this pseudo-class, not to familiar with it to be honest. **Disabling the text-shadow in the inspector seems to fix it though**. Perhaps that's an option.

Comment: no jumbling for me on chrome

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Mac. Strange, removing the text-shadow doesn't make a difference on my machine but removing the color attribute does!